# Is string an array or a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I got this tiny little program down here, that comes with preassigned 'count' number and then parses it to format of 'xxx', where x is a 0 or corresponding cipher (e.g from '6' I got 006 and from 234 I get 234). When I get it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count = 0;

    char number[2] = {0};

    int base0 = count % 10;
    int base1 = ((count % 100) - base0) / 10;
    int base2 = ((count % 1000) - base1) / 100;
    sprintf(number, "%d%d%d", base2, base1, base0); //print into the number variable
    printf("%s\n", number); 
}
```

everything is working fine, but if I switch 'number' variable definition with

```
char* number = NULL;
```

I get segmentation fault. Why is that? It should just point to the beggining of the string.

Comment: Both are illegal and cause UB. You should study about memory allocation.

Comment: In the first case (number[2] = {0}) you are assigning the ASCII character zero to every element of  the array "number". When you assign NULL to number you just have a pointer to a character named "number" which points to no memory address. You have to allocate memory for number.

Comment: I understand now. But how do you allocate enough memory for this?  char *number = malloc(sizeof(999)); works, but the sizeof(999) part doesn't seem to be the most elegant way

Comment: `sizeof(999)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.....that's not how it works.

Comment: So how could I optimize it for allocating memory only for 0-999 ? Not whole int range?

Comment: `Why is that? It should just point to the beggining of the string.` - you *specifically wrote* `number = NULL;`, so why would you expect it to contain anything other than NULL...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a string is represented as an array of characters; the line

```
char number[2] = { 0 };
```

therefore defines a two character array ('string') initialised with two null characters.

An array is a series of contiguous (read 'next to each other') blocks of memory that can each be individually accessed via the subscript operator (square brackets).

When you changed the above line to

```
char* number = NULL;
```

You are no longer defining a character array. In this case you are now defining a pointer to `char` variable. Because arrays are basically blocks of memory next to each other, if you know where the *first* element is, it is possible to then locate any of the others. So since the deference operator allows you to access the value pointed at by a pointer, you can access the **i**th element in a string with

```
*(char + i)
```

which in C is exactly equivalent to

```
char[i]
```

Now in your case, you haven't set the char* to point to actual memory containing a real string, you have assigned the NULL pointer, which means 'this pointer points nowhere'. Treating a char* as a string requires it to be dereferenced (following the pointer); however, dereferencing a NULL pointer is an undefined behaviour, which in this situation has caused a seg fault

Answer (score 0):

> *"everything is working fine,"*

Wait there. You already have sever shortage of required memory. In case of

```
  sprintf(number, "%d%d%d", base2, base1, base0);
```

`number` needs much more memory to stay within the bounds, so as is, your program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing out of bound memory. You need to allocate *enough* memory to hold the final *sting* to be held by `number`.

Anyways, `NULL` is defined to be an *invalid* memory location, accessing which invoke UB again, so you cannot use it to *store* anything, at all.

Comment: I don't think that there is a shortage. Maximum number is a 999 and my code with char number[2] = {0} parses it with success. See comments below 1st post

Comment: Actually a _null pointer_ does not point to a memory location at all. And `NULL` is just a macro with **a** (not **the**) _null pointer constant_.

Comment: @Olaf Right, so the `NULL` should be pointing to _some_ invalid memory location which should not be accessed. It can only bu used for comparison and as sentinel value cases, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: 1) `NULL` is a macro, thus just some replacement text. It does by definition not "point". 2) A _null pointer_ does not point **anywhere** by definition. It does not just point to "invalid" memory. (Actually, the values used by common implementations **are** valid addresses, e.g. `0x0` for ARM-MCUs which have memory at address `0x0`). See it as a special code which is not an address at all. Better designed languages than C provide a special keyword for that, e.g. `NIL` in Pascal/Modula/etc. or C++11 `nullptr` which explicitly has been added to get rid of that bad dualism of `0`.

Comment: Just to make clear: We should strongly differentiate between the language semantics and an actual implementation semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is a well-defined "nowhere" - it's an *invalid* pointer value that's guaranteed not to point to a function or an object in memory.  When you set `number` to `NULL`, you're saying that `number` isn't pointing anywhere meaningful.

Trying to work through an invalid pointer leads to undefined behavior - in this case, a segfault.

Arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing.  Array *expressions* will "decay" (be converted) to pointer types in most circumstances, but the *object* is always an array.

Answer (score 0):

char number[2]; gives you two bytes of memory for number
char * number = null; gives you zero bytes of memory for *number.

When you do sprintf, you are writing three bytes into the number.
When say "char *number = null", you are writing into null, which results in segfault.

When you do sprintf, you are writing 3 bytes into 2 bytes of allocated memory - you are overwriting 1 extra byte into stack.